# how to save video file into document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video

I am capturing video using following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
ipc.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
ipc.delegate = self;
//need to handle delegates methods 
//
ipc.allowsEditing = YES;
ipc.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;
ipc.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f; // 30 seconds
//temporary duation of 30 seconds for testing

ipc.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.movie"];
// ipc.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.movie", @"public.image", nil];
[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES]; 
//this controller allows to record the videos
```

and I can save recorded video to album using following code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{ 
    // recover video URL
    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    // check if video is compatible with album
    BOOL compatible = UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum([url path]);

    // save
    if (compatible){
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([url path], self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
        NSLog(@"saved!!!! %@",[url path]);
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

but I need to retrieve that file from album and need to store into document directory?

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 31):

Saving the video to the documents directory is as follows:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];
    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Why is atomically set to NO for [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO]?

Comment: I have a followup question too. Is there a way to save the video but without any compression? Ie copy video files as is.

Comment: Why it is saved as mp4? The file type can be MOV also right?

Answer (score 12):

Here is the swift code if anyone need it in future:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: videoURL)
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/vid1.mp4")

    videoData?.writeToFile(dataPath, atomically: false)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: You may also be able to specify paths.first, with the advantage that it won't fail if the list is of zero length.

Comment: If anyone having trouble with this, you can try videoData?.write(to: dataPath, options: .withoutOverwriting) .. this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark File Names and Paths
// Creates the path if it does not exist.
- (void)ensurePathAt:(NSString *)path {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ( [fm fileExistsAtPath:path] == false ) {
        [fm createDirectoryAtPath:path
      withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                       attributes:nil
                            error:NULL];
    }
}
- (NSString *)documentPath {
    if ( ! documentPath_ ) {
        NSArray *searchPaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        documentPath_ = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
        documentPath_=[documentPath_ stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"VideoAlbum"];
        [documentPath_ retain];
    }
    return documentPath_;
}

- (NSString *)audioPath {
    if ( ! AudioPath_ ) {
        AudioPath_ = [[self documentPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Demo"];
        NSLog(@"%@",AudioPath_);
        [AudioPath_ retain];
        [self ensurePathAt:AudioPath_];
    }
    return AudioPath_;
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        tempPath = [[self audioPath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.mp4",[NSDate date]];
        BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];

        NSLog(@"%hhd",success);
    }
    [[picker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Bit of R&D, this worked for me

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

{

```
 NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
  // Save video to app document directory

NSString *filePath = [url path];
NSString *pathExtension = [filePath pathExtension] ;
if ([pathExtension length] > 0)
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [filePath lastPathComponent]]];

   // Method last path component is used here, so that each video saved will get different name.

    NSError *error = nil ;
    BOOL res = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:localFilePath error:&error] ;

    if (!res)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]) ;
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"File saved at : %@",localFilePath);
    }
}
```

}

//Also when you have to check for same video already exist in app document directory and you  don't want create multiple copies of it then made some changes as below

```
NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSURL *videoAsset = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:videoAsset resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
{
    weakSelf.selectedFileName = [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename];
    NSLog(@"Video Filename %@",weakSelf.selectedFileName);

    // Save video to doc directory
    NSString *filePath = [url path];
    NSString *pathExtension = [filePath pathExtension] ;
    if ([pathExtension length] > 0)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", weakSelf.selectedFileName]];

        //check if same video is having its copy in app directory.
        //so that multiple entries of same file should not happen.

        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localFilePath];

        if (!fileExists)
        {
            NSError *error = nil ;

            BOOL res = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:localFilePath error:&error] ;

            if (!res)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]) ;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"File saved at : %@",localFilePath);
                weakSelf.filePathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:localFilePath];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"File exist at : %@",localFilePath);
            weakSelf.filePathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:localFilePath];
        }

    }
}
```

}

//Where weakSelf.selectedFileName & weakSelf.filePathURL are NSString and NSURL type properties of my class respectively.

Comment: Alas, I believe ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated. PHPhoto is needed, methinks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use NSFileManager's `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` method to move the video file to our app's document directory. It's more efficient.

Also we should get the extension of the video file and use it as extension of our local video file name.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] ;

    if ([info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        // video
        NSURL *url = [info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] ;
        NSString *filePath = [url path] ;
        NSString *pathExtension = [filePath pathExtension] ;
        if ([pathExtension length] > 0) {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
            NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp.%@", pathExtension]] ;
            NSError *error = nil ;
            BOOL res = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:localFilePath error:&error] ;
            if (!res) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Good, work well for me too. Update for Swift 4.0:
        let pathExtension = videoPath.pathExtension
        if !pathExtension.isEmpty,
            let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let localFile = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("temp.\(pathExtension)").path
            do {
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(atPath: videoPath.path, toPath: localFile)
            } catch {
                print("Cannot move the video \(error)")
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
 videoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
urlString=[urlvideo path];
NSLog(@"path url %@",videoUrl);
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *sourcePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfilename.mp4"];

[videoData writeToFile:sourcePath atomically:YES];
//Below code will save video to iOS Device
 ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoUrl
                            completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){/*notify of completion*/}];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
    videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]as? NSURL
    print(videoURL!)

    let urlData=NSData(contentsOf: videoURL as! URL)

    if((urlData) != nil)
    {
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectory = path.first! as NSString
        let fileName = "Video.MOV"
        let PDFPathFileName = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

        print(PDFPathFileName)

        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
            urlData?.write(toFile: PDFPathFileName, atomically: true)
        })

        do {
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL as! URL , options: nil)
            let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
            let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            imgView.image = thumbnail
            // thumbnail here

        } catch let error {
            print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3/4

> ```
> func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
>         // recover video URL
>         let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
>         // check if video is compatible with album
>         let compatible: Bool = UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum((url?.path)!)
>         // save
>         if compatible {
>             UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum((url?.path)!, self, nil, nil)
>             print("saved!!!! \(String(describing: url?.path))")
>         }
>         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
>     }
> //   error
>     func video(_ videoPath: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
>     }
> ```

saving example Path:-

```
"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EA53C844-7931-446C-800D-DA90717426BB/tmp/xxxxxx.MOV"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Call this function, and it will do every thing for you :)**

```
    private func saveVideo(url:URL) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        guard let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent).path) {
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let location = location else { return }
                let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)

                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
                    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (authorizationStatus: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
                        if authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: destinationURL)}) { completed, error in
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        if completed {
                                            self.view.makeToast(NSLocalizedString("Video Saved!", comment: "Video Saved!"), duration: 3.0, position: .center)
                                        } else {
                                            print(error!)
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                } catch { print(error) }

                }.resume()
        } else {
            print("File already exists at destination url")
        }
    }
}
```