# Play a video from a local path

Tags: ios, swift

I've created an application which record a video and save it to the photoalbum this works fine. However when i try to play it using the [Player](https://github.com/piemonte/Player) Library, which seem to be very simple it does not play the video. I've tried with the sample url and that works fine. How come it does not work with my path, even though it is saved and shown in the photoalbum.

in below code i save the video to a specific path and when this is done i set it as NSURL in the as in the `Player` library. What could trigger this? does it save the video in the background or what could trigger this behaviour?

**Record video has ended**

```
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

        videoOutput.stopRecording()
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum("\(documentsPath)/\(randomVideoFileName).mov", nil, nil, nil)


        previewVideoView.setUrl(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(documentsPath)/\(randomVideoFileName).mov"))
        previewVideoView.view.hidden = false
        previewVideoView.playFromBeginning()


    }
```

i've even tried to check whether the path exist using this code and it exists?

```
        let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(randomVideoFileName).mov"
        if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath))
        {
            print("Exists")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is missing here is that you are not waiting till the video is fully saved into the photo album. Try making all the setters in the callback like this:

After `videoOutput.stopRecording()`, start saving the video, and add a callback method to get alerted when it's finished (for more information see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum)):

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum("\(documentsPath)/\(randomVideoFileName).mov", self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)`
```

And after that add this method:

```
func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {

    if error != nil {
        // Report error to user
        return;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

        previewVideoView.setUrl(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(documentsPath)/\(randomVideoFileName).mov"))
        previewVideoView.view.hidden = false
        previewVideoView.playFromBeginning()

    })
}
```

Comment: ooh okay thank you another question is it possible to play a video without saving it to photosalbum ?

Comment: @PeterPik Yes! you can store it in the document directory. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916305/how-to-save-video-file-into-document-directory. You need to be careful about this because as soon as you store the video locally - lets say inside the app - , your app data will increase, hence your app size will increase, and users wont like apps with gigas of size (cause they are videos), so you'll need to manage this.