# How to save video to app's directory and playback in view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

[I'm trying to save a video in my app directory and then play it back in my view controller. I'm having an issue with saving and making the path. Can anyone help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sy07.png)

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {

```
        // Save the video to the app directory
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
        let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: videoURL as URL)
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0] as AnyObject
        let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/vid1.mp4")

        videoData?.write(toFile: dataPath, atomically: false)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func playVideoAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0] as AnyObject
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/vid1.mp4")

    let videoAsset = (AVAsset(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath) as URL))
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoAsset)

    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player

    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true)
    {
        playerViewController.player!.play()
    }
}
```

[how to save video file into document directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916305/how-to-save-video-file-into-document-directory)

I've used code from this link but with the update to xcode 8/swift 3 it is not as helpful. Been stuck on this problem for awhile now.

Comment: Please post some code. What have you tried?

Comment: The first line when clicked shows my code but I'll try to edit my post so it's visible immediately.  New to stackoverflow and posting pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `PHImageManager.requestExportSession(forVideo:options:)`. This will prepare the asset asynchronously (including downloading it if needed), and create an `AVExportSession` you can use to save the file. By specifying you want the original, and to passthrough the content (if possible) you should get the best quality video available.

```
var dataPath: URL {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths[0])
    return documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("/vid1.mp4")
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL

    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
    let asset = assets.object(at: 0)
    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original
    PHImageManager.default().requestExportSession(forVideo: asset, options: options, exportPreset: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) { (exportSession, info) in
        guard let session = exportSession else { return }
        session.outputURL = self.dataPath
        session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        session.exportAsynchronously {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you didn't want to save to disk but just playback, you can use `requestPlayerItem` to get an `AVPlayerItem` you can use in your player:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL

    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
    let asset = assets.object(at: 0)
    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.version = .original
    PHImageManager.default().requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: options) { (playerItem, info) in
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer and new way to look at it. Can you show me what the playVideoAction method would look like? I implement the requestPlayerItem but I don't think I did it right.